# Thymeleaf security is not rendering to html

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am using spring boot from spring.start.io
I have a problem where my view(thymleaf) doesn't render `sec:` tags to proper html
my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>security</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <thymeleaf.version>3.0.2.RELEASE</thymeleaf.version>
        <thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>2.2.0</thymeleaf-layout-dialect.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

My thymeleaf template

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/extras/spring-security">
<th:block th:replace="~{fragments/main-page-fragments:: htmlHeadTag}">
</th:block>
<body>
<th:block th:replace="~{fragments/main-page-fragments:: navBar}">
</th:block>
<h1>Home</h1>
<div sec:authentication="name"></div>
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
    Za Admina
</div>
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ROLE_USER')">
    Za user
</div>
<div sec:authentication="name"></div>
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('ADMIN')">
    Za Admina
</div>
<div sec:authorize="hasRole('USER')">
    Za user
</div>
<th:block th:replace="~{fragments/main-page-fragments:: bootstrapScripts}">
</th:block>
</body>
</html>
```

And the result is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jk9Pi.jpg

What exactly have i done wrong? I even have intellisence for the roles, i linked the correct dependecies i link the sec xml tag as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `sec:` extension for simple Spring Security integration.

Conditional block depending on role:

```xml
<div th:if="${#request.isUserInRole('ADMIN')}">
  Za Admina
</div>
```

Print username:

```xml
<div th:text="${#request.userPrincipal.name}"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

i think it's caused by not having the spring security dialect added to the TemplateEngine. I'm not sure how you set up your WebMvcConfig, but as an example:

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity4.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine;
import org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.ClassLoaderTemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.TemplateResolver;
import org.thymeleaf.templateresolver.UrlTemplateResolver;

@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public TemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    TemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setPrefix("views/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public UrlTemplateResolver urlTemplateResolver() {
    return new UrlTemplateResolver();
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    templateEngine.addTemplateResolver(urlTemplateResolver());
    templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver thymeleafViewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver vr = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    vr.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    vr.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    vr.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    return vr;
}
```

}

Greetings
Marian

@Edit:
I added a complete Example of an WebMvcConfig. For this Example the Views would be located in Resources/views, but you can ofc set it up however you'd like to.

Comment: hey, i have setup my spring Sercurity, it works as intended  and my user implements extends role atc.. everything is by the book there, just thymleaf cause the problem. Now to your answer, what exactly is `templateResolver()` and `urlTemplateResolver()`

Comment: So the implementation of the templateResolver() and the urlTemplateResolver always depends on the way your project is set up. I just extended my example to give a more complete overview over WebMvcConfig. I hope this helps you.

Comment: ty for the attention, but i found the answer, in pom.xml if you link `<dependency>
   <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
   <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
   <version>3.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>` with the 3.0.1 version isntead ofthe latest it work perfectly